# Accurate algorithm for normalizing taxonomy terms?

Tags: string, taxonomy, string-matching, faceted-search

I'm developing a shopping comparison website, and the project is in a very advanced stage. We index 50 million products daily using merchant feeds from various affiliate networks. Most of the problems I had is already solved, including the majority of the performance bottlenecks.

What is my problem: Please, first of all, we are using apache solr with drupal BUT, this problem IS NOT specific to drupal or solr, if you do not have knowledge of them, it doesn't matter.

We receive product feeds from over 2000 different merchants, and those feeds are a mess. They have no specific pattern, each merchant send the feeds the way they want. We already solved many problems regarding this, but one remains. Normalizing the taxonomy terms for the faceted browsing functionality.

Suppose that I have a "Narrow by Brands" browsing facet on my website. Now suppose that 100 merchants offer products from Microsoft. Now comes the problem. Some merchants put in the "Brands" column of the data feed "Microsoft", others "Microsoft, Inc.", others "Microsoft Corporation" others "Products from Microsoft", etc... there is no specific pattern between merchants and worst, some individual merchants are so sloppy that they have different strings for the same brand IN THE SAME DATA FEED.

We do not want all those different brands appearing in the navigation. We have a manual solution to the problem where we manually map the imported brands to the "good" brands table ("Microsoft Corporation" -> "Microsoft", "Products from Microsoft" -> "Microsoft", etc..). We have something like 10,000 brands in the database and this is doable. The problem is when it comes with bigger things like "Authors". When we import books into the system, there are over 800,000 authors and we have the same problem and this is not doable by hand mapping. The problem is the same: "Tom Mike Apostol", "Tom M. Apostol", "Apostol, Tom M.", etc...

Does anybody know a good way to automatically solve this problem with an acceptable degree of accuracy (85%-95% accuracy)?

Thanks you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some idea that comes to my mind, altough it's just a loose thought:

1. Convert names to initials (in your example: TMA). Treat '-' as spaces, so fe. Antoine de Saint-Exupéry would be ADSE. Problem here is how to treat ",", altough, it's common usage is to have surname before forename, so just swapping positions should work (so A,TM would be TM,A, get rid of comma - TMA).
2. Filters authors in database by those initials
3. For each intitial, if you have whole name (Tom, Apostol) check if it match, otherwise (M.) consider it a match automatically.
4. If you want some tolerance, you can compare names with Levenshtein distance and tolerate some differences ([here](http://www.merriampark.com/ldplsql.htm4.) you have Oracle implementation)
5. Names that match you treat as the same authors, to find the whole name, for each initial (T, M, A) you look up your filtered authors (after step 2) and try to find one without just initial (M.) but with whole name (Mike), if you can't find one, use initial. Therefore, each of examples you gave would be converted to the same value, which would be full name (Tom Mike Apostol).

Things that are worth to think about:
Include mappings for name synonyms (would be more likely maximally hundred of records, like Thomas <-> Tom
This way is crucial to have valid initials (no M instead of N etc.).

edit: I've coded such thing some time ago, when I had to identify a person by it's signature, ignoring scanning problems, people sometimes sign by Name S. Surname, or N.S. or just by Name Surname (which is another thing maybe you should consider in the solution, to allow the algorithm to ignore second name, altough in your situation it would be rather rare to ommit someone's second name I guess).